# Android global variable vs cannot resolve method getApplication()

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a global variable as shown in mutliple other stack answers, but when I follow all those instructions, I get "cannot resolve method getApplication()" when trying to get or set this variable in any other activity. What am I doing wrong and how do I then get/set this variable? Here's the MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    private int globalVariable_Move;

    public int getGlobalVariable_Move() {
        return globalVariable_Move;
    }

    public void setGlobalVariable_Move(int value) {
        globalVariable_Move = value;
    }
```

And here's the another Activity code:

```
public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

        gameView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                int tempGlobalVariableMove = ((MainActivity) this.getApplication()).getGlobalVariable_Move();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `getApplication()` returns the `Application` not your `MainActivity`. I would suggest you to use shared preferences for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement it in Application custom class not in Activity. Something like this:

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application {

    private Tracker mTracker;

    public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
        if (mTracker == null) {
            mTracker = new Tracker();
        }
        return mTracker;
    }
}
```

And get this from any Activity class like:

```
CustomApplication app = (CustomApplication) getApplication();
app.getDefaultTracker();
```

Or better use Singleton pattern to store global state and variables.